# Rails image resize before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, minimagick

I'd like to resize an image before it gets saved. Currently, this is done in the controller:

```
shrink = MiniMagick::Image.new(params[:user][:photo].tempfile.path)
shrink.resize "500x500"
```

That works but it doesn't feel very skinny.  I'd rather have this in the model, which I assume would look something like this:

```
    before_save :resize_image

    def resize_image
      shrink = MiniMagick::Image.new(self.photo)
      shrink.resize "500x500"
    end
```

This; however, yealds the error:

```
`magick mogrify -resize 500x500 #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007ffc866418d0>` failed with error:
mogrify: unable to open image '#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007ffc866418d0>': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496.
mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
 excluded from capture: Not configured to send/capture in environment 'development'
```

I've tried variations such as `self.photo.path` but so far I have been unable to find a method works for the active storage object. What am I missing?  Am I correct in assuming that something like this belongs in the model in the first place rather than the controller?

Comment: Not An answer: WHy would you use MIniMagick for that, ActiveStorage provides mini_magick inbuilt. And it is clean.

Comment: I was not aware of this, how would I implement an image resize on upload with ActiveStorage not using MiniMagick.  Also, what do you mean by clean?

Comment: Checkout Image Variant Options: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html

Comment: From what I can tell this is only creating a variant of the original saved image, is there a way to shrink the image before saving it?